# Center map on pin location

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I try to display a pin in a center of a map, unfortunatelly something is wrong and the pin shows up in the middle- right of the screen.

this is my code

```
// Single annotation
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:self.detailsAnnotation completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
    for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
    {
        // Process the placemark.
        self.latitudeOfPlaceFromTable = aPlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude;
        self.longitudeOfPlaceFromTable = aPlacemark.location.coordinate.longitude;
        MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion;

        // 1 Center
        CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
        zoomLocation.latitude = self.latitudeOfPlaceFromTable;
        zoomLocation.longitude = self.longitudeOfPlaceFromTable;

        // Span
        MKCoordinateSpan span;
        span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
        span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;

        // 2 Region
        viewRegion.center = zoomLocation;
        viewRegion.span = span;

        // 3 Add an annotation
        MKPointAnnotation * point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        point.coordinate = zoomLocation;
        point.title = self.titleAnnotation;
        point.subtitle = self.detailsAnnotation;
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];

        // 4 Center the map on pin
        [self.mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
    }
}];
```

Can someone gives some help ? Thanks

Comment: I had a similar problem once, it may sound silly, but try setting the center after setting the span. Does that help?

Comment: no, the pin is always in the right side of screen, not in center ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your last line of code with this one:
`[self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion] animated:YES];`

Usually MapView can't display exact region that you try to set, because map isn't flat.
From Apple documentation on `regionThatFits` method:

> Adjusts the aspect ratio of the specified region to ensure that it fits in the map view’s frame.
>   You can use this method to normalize the region values before displaying them in the map. This method returns a new region that both contains the specified region and fits neatly inside the map view’s frame.

Update:
Another suggestion: be sure that map view width isn't more then actual screen width. In other case map view frame can overstep the right bound of screen that will results in wrong center point.

Comment: @Dev790 I have updated my answer. See "Update" section

Comment: i think you are right, i just click in storyboard "Add missing contraints" for MapView and now everyting is ok. I changed too  in storyboard for mapView, the mode to "Center" (i'm not sure this is necessary). Thanks everyone !!!